# Must WebAPI uploads be Async?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I've been reading up on ASP.NET WebAPI file uploads on the web and StackOverflow.

All of the questions I've seen (directly or indirectly) refer to [the MSDN article example with the async upload](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data,-part-2).

Is this the de facto way to process file uploads? Must a file upload to WebAPI use `Task<>` and `async`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend just asked me about this issue and the short answer, I believe, is yes... with caveats.

The relevant API is provided by the extension methods defined on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontentmultipartextensions(v=vs.118).aspx. I've hunted around for synchronous versions of these methods but to no avail.

Obviously the return value from `ReadAsMultipartAsync<T>` is a `Task<T>`, on which you can call `Wait()` to force synchronicity. You can then dispense with the async on the method declaration in your controller.

I've not tried it yet so maybe it works, maybe it doesn't - although there's no obvious reason why it wouldn't.

I suppose the question I should ask is why you'd like to implement a synchronous upload given MS are trying pretty hard to force developers down the async route? (Not that this is necessarily good or appropriate in all cases.)

Comment: This is correct, async (usually does not change semantics. It only changes the way the operation is started and completed.

Comment: Never mind being "forced", this is pretty much a case where being async is a no-brainer. Why would you want to do otherwise.

Comment: Well... I don't love async, although I do make use of it from time to time when it fits. In this case it doesn't seem like a bad solution but I'm curious as to why StuperUser wants to go down the synchronous route. In the end we decided to stick with async because for our case we couldn't see a reason not to.